# Ray Tune random search indefinitely many samples

Tags: python-3.x, ray, ray-tune

Code sample to illustrate the issue:

```py
from ray import tune


def objective(step, alpha, beta):
    return (0.1 + alpha * step / 100)**(-1) + beta * 0.1


def training_function(config):
    # Hyperparameters
    alpha, beta = config["alpha"], config["beta"]
    for step in range(10):
        # Iterative training function - can be any arbitrary training procedure.
        intermediate_score = objective(step, alpha, beta)
        # Feed the score back back to Tune.
        tune.report(mean_loss=intermediate_score)


analysis = tune.run(
    training_function,
    config={
        "alpha": tune.grid_search([0.001, 0.01, 0.1]),
        "beta": tune.choice(list(range(10000)))
    },
    num_samples=1000000)
```

Problem I face is that `tune.run` call will mandatory sample search space `num_samples` times before starting to execute the first trial.

Question: is it possible to make Tune sample search space after each trial?

It is possible to limit number of concurrent trials for `tune.suggest.Searcher`-descendant algorithms (`AxSearch`, for example), using `ConcurrencyLimiter` wrapper around search algorithm. But how can I do this for random search?

Comment: RayTune currently auto-generates all of the samples ahead of time. Could you post an issue on Github? This feature request makes sense.

Comment: I've created a workaround by using custom Searcher and Concurrency limited on top of it. I think once it's ready, I'll post an issue together with PR and update this question.